# Playing a sound in Visual Code application when receiving data from an Arduino

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

E.g.: When Arduino sends Visual Code the data string 'hihat' a hihat sound is supposed to be played.
Currently, it shows me the received data.
I figured that I can play a sound when pressing a button, but the sound is supposed to play automatically when receiving data. Is it even possible? I would be delighted and am thankful for any help.

```
/* Windows Forms-App .NET 6.0
 * Install System.IO.Ports
 * Install NAudio
 */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace Orbita_sound
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        delegate void serialCallBack(string val);

        WaveStream streambass = new WaveFileReader("Kick 1.wav");
        WaveStream streamhihat = new WaveFileReader("Hihat 2.wav");
        WaveStream streamsnare = new WaveFileReader("Snare 2.wav");
        WaveStream streamcrash = new WaveFileReader("Crash 2.wav");

        WaveOut bass = new WaveOut();
        WaveOut hihat = new WaveOut();
        WaveOut snare = new WaveOut();
        WaveOut crash = new WaveOut();

        string incomString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bass.Init(streambass);
            hihat.Init(streamhihat);
            snare.Init(streamsnare);
            crash.Init(streamcrash);
        }

        private void PlaySound()
        {
            if (incomString == "bass")
            {
                streambass.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);
                bass.Play();
            }
            else if (incomString == "hihat")
            {
                streamhihat.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);
                hihat.Play();
            }
            else if (incomString == "snare")
            {
                streamsnare.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);
                snare.Play();
            }
            else if (incomString == "crash")
            {
                streamcrash.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);
                crash.Play();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;

            PlaySound();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            incomString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            setText(incomString);
        }

        private void setText(string val)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                serialCallBack scb = new serialCallBack(setText);
                this.Invoke(scb, new object[] { val });
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you want a sound to play in "Visual Code", do you mean **in your application**? Because Visual Studio Code and your application are **not** the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to play the sound in the application.